# Uploading files to server and storing files to disk with Spring Framework 3

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, filesystems

I need to upload files to server and that part I have successfully done, but now I need to know what is best practise to save files that are related to database items to disk with Spring and how that is actually done with Spring.

I thought it could be good way to use database table id in folder for example:

```
context_path/table_name/id/filename.file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three options:

- store them in the database as blobs
- store them in a folder external to the web application (and configurable in the application properties) and keep reference (in the db) to the subfolder+filename in the database
- push the items to some other storage, like a content repository, and keep reference (in the db) to the unique key of the resource

This is the case not only with spring, but with any application.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to save the file in a directory which has the name of the ID of the row in the database is pretty good. There is no good way to make this really 100% transaction safe (filesystems don't really understand the concept of "transaction" or "two phase commit".

Just make sure that the `context_path` is configurable so the data can be moved around easily.

Comment: I think he successfully handle the upload

Comment: Yeah, missed that. Updated my answer.

Comment: Could someone maybe post some parts of his/her code? How did you move e.g. a MultiPart file to its destination? What steps are necessary?

Comment: @Czar: Just have a look at the sample code for, say, FileUpload: http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html  If you can't get it to work, ask a specific question.

Comment: Thanks. I made it work. Could also move files on my server disk, but finally decided to put in database. Thanks though...